# Docker containers exit after start command

Tags: docker, containers, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a docker container that adds python image from docker hub using a chef recipe. After chef-client run, I can see the container but it is not getting started even after issuing start command.

Here is my cookbook recipe to pull python image,

```
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end

docker_image 'python' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end

docker_container 'testpy' do
  repo 'python'
  tag 'latest'
  action :run
end
```

Below is the issue with the container,

> root@ubuntunode2-vm:~# docker start 2e512235c0fe
>   2e512235c0fe
>
> root@ubuntunode2-vm:~# docker exec -it 2e512235c0fe bash
>
> Error response from daemon: Container 2e512235c0fe50b6314648b9d6eae6162790e0793008344d27288d95c69d4923 is not running

Hightlighted container in the screenshot is created through chef recipe

Comment: are you runnig chef-client inside a container or inside a vm?

Comment: inside a vm, "ubuntunode-vm" is my vm name

Comment: check the output of `docker logs 2e512235c0fe`

Comment: @DusanGligoric I tried but it gives nothing

root@ubuntunode2-vm:~# docker logs 2e512235c0fe
root@ubuntunode2-vm:~#

Comment: can you do `docker ps -a` and check command it ran on that container, should be `python3`? Also exit status would be good

Comment: @DusanGligoric
root@ubuntunode2-vm:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
2e512235c0fe        python:latest       "python3"                4 hours ago         Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                         testpy
51734a337737        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"              2 days ago          Up 22 minutes                                     Test

"testpy" is the container created through chef recipe
"Test" container was created manually using docker run command

Comment: ye it has to do with `interactive mode` for sure, try running `docker -d python` and you will see it exit with status 0

Comment: try adding `tty: true` to your docker_container block

Comment: @DusanGligoric Container status changed to up after adding "tty true" in cookbook. Issue resoslved.

Comment: Ill add an answer, approve it if you may :)

Answer (score 1):

since your question does not include full details, the answer will be focused on your recipe.

under the assumption that you are using docker cookbook:

1. install docker engine. you can do that using [`docker_installtion`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_installation) resource. i prefer [`docker_installation_package`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_installation_package) resource, in order to use the linux repository package of docker and pin the package version
2. once docker engine is installed, let's make sure that docker engine daemon (service) is running. for that you can use the (native) [`service`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) resource. note that, there is [`docker_service`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_service) resource within the docker cookbook, but i prefer the native service method
3. pull the docker image using [`docker_image`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_image) resource
4. use [`docker_container`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_container) resource to run the pulled docker image

Answer (score 0):

Python's interactive shell needs tty in order to run, add `tty: true` to the docker_container block and you should be good to go.